# A way for multiple inputType in EditText in Android Kotlin using Anko

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I noticed that there is no way for anko to add multiple inputTypes for editText as xmls did.

In xmls it would have been as simple as:

```
android:inputType = "numberSigned|numberDecimal"
```

But in Anko it recieves only an int as an argument for inputType.

```
editText {
    inputType = 2002
}
```

I've tried to search for other ways but I keep seeing xml tutorials and I have not seen any Anko example where it has two inputTypes in it. Is there a way to do this in Anko or should I revert to using xmls for this particular activity?

Comment: `numberSigned  or numberDecimal`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce: I had wanted to add them both as the inputType but since editText in Anko only accepts int, I don't know how you'd be able to mix them both in.

Comment: @Blender Have you tried using function `or()` between multiple values? `or()` is a infix function.

Comment: I meant the bitwise operator.